# ImageView inside RelativeLayout not obbeing its parent height

Tags: android

I have the following code in **create_button.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="60dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:background="@color/green">
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/test_button_image"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/backImage"
          android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
       </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This piece of code is included as a fragment of an application as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:baselineAligned="false"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include android:id="@+id/buttonCreate"
       layout="@layout/create_button"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </include>
</LinearLayout>
```

But my image is not obbeing to the `RelativeLayout` **layout_height** of 60dp and it's expandig to its full original height.

I tried to change its `layout_height` to `match_parent`, with no luck. It expands full screen height.

How can I make this image to be the same height as its parent `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Change this line in your `ImageView` `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: I tried that, and then the button will expand  its main container layout height.

Comment: What you want the height of the image to be ? Same as `RelativeLayout` right ?

Comment: Did you change the height to match_parent of your image view ? It will never take to fullscreen, also you are using padding in your `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think following code will work for you.

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:padding="3dp"
android:background="@color/green">
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/test_button_image"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/backImage"
      android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
      android:layout_height="60dp"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
   </ImageView></RelativeLayout>
```

**Exchange the height of Relative layout with ImageView and vice versa.**

Comment: It does work, but I was trying to find a dynamic way of binding to its parent height.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will never expandig to its full original height.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@color/green"
android:padding="3dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/test_button_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/backImage" >
</ImageView>
```